# Post Envia dados, mas webapi captura null

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api

Estou pegando esse cabeçalho pelo fiddler.

```
POST http://localhost:8887/api/values HTTP/1.1 
Host: localhost:8887
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 352
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:8383
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8383/comandaApp/principal.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
{"IDEmpresa":"1","IDTabelaPreco":"1","numeroVendedor":"1","IDCupomFiscal":"","IDGrupo":"1","IDUsuario":"1","IDVendedor":"1","NMMesa":"3","IDMesa":"3","STCartao":"N","STViagem":"N","STDelivery":"N","modalidadeDelivery":"","observacaoDelivery":"","localEntrega":"","comandaItemPojo":[{"IDProduto":"162","NRReferencia":"","QTDProduto":1,"observacao":""}]}
```

**O Envio para a webAPI**

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://localhost:8887/api/values",
        data: JSON.stringify(comandaPojo),
        success: function(retorno)
        {
        //códigos....
    }
```

**Na WEBAPI está assim**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace webapi_MVC5.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            string a = value; //VALUE RETORNA NULL
            string b = "x";
        }
    }
}
```

Já adicionei está linha no **webconfig**

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

Eu só recebo `NULL` no parâmetro `value`.

O que pode ser? meu IIS tá conectado como o meu usuário local (com senha). Tem alguma coisa a ver?

Comment: você realmente quer pegar a string do JSON?

Comment: o que tem em `comandaPojo`? qual é o conteudo?

Answer (score 1):

Esta é a maneira errada de passar parâmetros para seu *Controller*.

Se a ideia é passar um tipo complexo, a melhor forma de fazê-lo é criando uma classe que receba estes dados, aproveitando o recurso de *Model Binding* que o Web API tem nativo:

```
public class ValoresViewModel
{
    public int IDEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int IDTabelaPreco { get; set; }
    public int numeroVendedor { get; set; }
    public int IDCupomFiscal { get; set; }
    public int IDGrupo { get; set; }
    public int IDUsuario { get; set; }
    public int IDVendedor { get; set; }
    public int NMMesa { get; set; }
    public int IDMesa { get; set; }
    public String STCartao { get; set; }
    public String STViagem { get; set; }
    public String STDelivery { get; set; }
    public String modalidadeDelivery { get; set; }
    public String observacaoDelivery { get; set; }
    public string localEntrega { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ComandaItemViewModel> comandaItemPojo { get; set; }
}
```

E `ComandaItemViewModel` será:

```
public class ComandaItemViewModel
{
    public int IDProduto { get; set; }
    public String NRReferencia { get; set; }
    public int QTDProduto { get; set; }
    public String observacao { get; set; }
}
```

O *Controller*, portanto, fica assim:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(ValoresViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Coloque sua lógica de negócios aqui, usando os dados de viewModel.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Está chegando null porque a sua chamada não condiz com a assinatura do método. Tente mudar o `data` para isso:

```
data: { 'value' : comandaPojo }
```